# Git push subtree fail unknown revision or path possibly due to missing git-subtree-split commit

Tags: git, git-push, subtree

I have been using git subtree to embed a repo within a folder of our main project. I am not sure what has happened, but pushing the subtree now fails to update the remote repo.

The command I use to push is:

```
git subtree push --prefix themes/natra https://github.com/OpenSID/tema-natra.git premium
```

The error message is:

```
   fatal: ambiguous argument '3f44cc87ceb87df1d9171096596a824fc3050a27^{commit}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
could not rev-parse split hash 3f44cc87ceb87df1d9171096596a824fc3050a27 from commit 8577911bf6183497cc246aa620e7be1b6becec29
```

I am not able to find the commit/hash 3f44cc87ceb87df1d9171096596a824fc3050a27 in the repo. In the following gitx image [Commit is git-subtree-split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tMln.jpg), I can see that the commit is a git-subtree-split. But it appears to no longer exist in the repo.

How can I bypass or recover from this apparent missing commit? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is *probably* a bug in `git subtree`, which has some known bugs. See the Git mailing list archive for details. There's nobody actively maintaining `git subtree` at the moment, as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for info @torek. As I am not in a position to help debug `git subtree`, it looks like I will need to look at replacing the use of `git subtree`.

Answer (score 1):

As I [answered](https://lore.kernel.org/git/61ee8bec-1e6c-e3c7-2cef-7520f376c18c@gmail.com/) to you on the Git mailing list, this happens because the `premium` branch at https://github.com/OpenSID/tema-natra.git was force-pushed.

To work around this, simply fetch the commit by its hash (it's still [available on GitHub](https://github.com/OpenSID/tema-natra/commit/3f44cc87ceb87df1d9171096596a824fc3050a27)):

```
git fetch https://github.com/OpenSID/tema-natra.git 3f44cc87ceb87df1d9171096596a824fc3050a27
```

and then you *should* be able to run your `git subtree push` command (though you might need to force-push...)

Comment: Thanks @philb.  The `git subtree push` command now no longer complains about the missing commit. However, it still fails, where the debug messages show that a large number of commits are incorrect order. Here is an excerpt:

`Using cachedir: /Users/eddieridwan/projects/jimmybox/public/premium/.git/subtree-cache/50582`

`Looking for prior splits...`

`Processing commit: 1fbbdda4f0ef15794eeb4a343d3fb1bf17fbb853`

 ` parents: c75f7cab156c91a1bf3b36658e1ac94dd1905bba`

 `   incorrect order: c75f7cab156c91a1bf3b36658e1ac94dd1905bba`

Comment: Could this be because incorrect info is now in the subtree-cache? Is deleting the cache something worth trying? Thanks.